# How do I get around Rkt's systemd-nspawn symlink issue?

Tags: ruby, rkt

I'm trying to make a simple Ruby app in a Rkt container, but my build script keeps giving me variations on:

```
Warning: "/bin/sh" is a symlink, which systemd-nspawn version 219 might error on
Directory /too/long/for/so/.acbuild/target lacks the binary to execute or doesn't 
    look like a binary tree. Refusing.
run: non-zero exit code: 1
Ending the build
```

**Can anyone tell me the usual way to work around this?**

Here is my build script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

acbuildend () {
    export EXIT=$?;
    acbuild --debug end && exit $EXIT;
}
acbuild --debug begin
trap acbuildend EXIT

rm -f sputnik2.aci

acbuild set-name jhallpr.com/sputnik

acbuild dependency add quay.io/coreos/alpine-sh
acbuild run -- apk update
acbuild run -- apk add ruby ruby-io-console

acbuild copy-to-dir ./sputnik2 /usr/src/app/sputnik2
acbuild set-working-directory /usr/src/app/sputnik2

acbuild run -- gem install bundler --no-doc --no-ri
acbuild run -- /bin/sh -c "bundle install"     # <-- *falls over here*

acbuild set-exec -- /usr/bin/ruby sputnik2.rb
acbuild write sputnik2.aci
```

Note that I'm shelling out here (`acbuild run -- /bin/sh -c...`) because bundler complains when it is run as root.  But the symlink thing seems to be a very common problem.  For example, if I install bundler via `acbuild run -- apk add`, the script complains that `bundle` is a symlink...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgrade to systemd version greater than 230.

Comment: I was hoping for a workaround for 230, I suppose. But from the dearth of comments here I'm guessing there isn't one.  So your answer is clearly the correct one.